# Relabelling a vector of repeating bouts of 0 1 so each bout of 1 is unique in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I've got a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
time <- c(1:250)
trial <- rep(1, 250)
X <- sample(200, 250, replace=TRUE)
Y <- sample(200, 250, replace=TRUE)
follow <- c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 25), rep(0, 5), rep(1, 50), rep(0, 55), rep(1, 30), rep(0, 35), rep(1, 10), rep(0, 20))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(trial, time, X, Y, follow))
```

I've got a vector called follow, which just acts as a label for when a certain behavior is being exhibited. However, I'd like each instance of when 1 appears to be unique, like this:

```
time <- c(1:250)
trial <- rep(1, 250)
X <- sample(200, 250, replace=TRUE)
Y <- sample(200, 250, replace=TRUE)
follow <- c(rep(0, 20), rep(1, 25), rep(0, 5), rep(2, 50), rep(0, 55), rep(3, 30), rep(0, 35), rep(4, 10), rep(0, 20))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(trial, time, X, Y, follow))
```

Is there a good way to do this? Thanks all!

Comment: Please let SO-members know if the solution in my post works or not. If not, maybe I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tidyverse option.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mutate(df, follow = if_else(follow == 1, 
                            cumsum(replace_na(lag(follow) < follow, 0)),
                            0)) 

#     trial time   X   Y follow
# 1       1    1 188  48      0
# 2       1    2  53 122      0
# 3       1    3 197 191      0
# 4       1    4 123  50      0
# 5       1    5  18 142      0
# 6       1    6  36  29      0
# 7       1    7 101 111      0
# 8       1    8  91  10      0
# 9       1    9 185  36      0
# 10      1   10  72  83      0
# 11      1   11 138  94      0
# 12      1   12 193  25      0
# 13      1   13  34  17      0
# 14      1   14  51 162      0
# 15      1   15 141 106      0
# 16      1   16  99 193      0
# 17      1   17  77  58      0
# 18      1   18  96  12      0
# 19      1   19  25 119      0
# 20      1   20 173  17      0
# 21      1   21  78 141      1
# 22      1   22  73 184      1
# 23      1   23 145 103      1
# 24      1   24 161  36      1
# 25      1   25  38  99      1
# 26      1   26  56 178      1
# 27      1   27  39  95      1
# 28      1   28 109  31      1
# 29      1   29 184 119      1
# 30      1   30  84 132      1
# 31      1   31 103 150      1
# 32      1   32 177  80      1
# 33      1   33 153 129      1
# 34      1   34 121  25      1
# 35      1   35 184 158      1
# 36      1   36 190  16      1
# 37      1   37  29 165      1
# 38      1   38 102  51      1
# 39      1   39 105  17      1
# 40      1   40  71   5      1
# 41      1   41  10   5      1
# 42      1   42 160  95      1
# 43      1   43 143  96      1
# 44      1   44 101  11      1
# 45      1   45 154 127      1
# 46      1   46  20 133      0
# 47      1   47 199 192      0
# 48      1   48  83   3      0
# 49      1   49  22  96      0
# 50      1   50  86  57      0
# 51      1   51 163  87      2
```